# Inflate layout programmatically within another layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-inflate

I need help with my android app. I need inflate a layout within another layout and I dont know how I do. My xml code is this:

- item.xml - I need inflate multiple xml (depending on a variable number)

  ```
      <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/cartel_N1"
           android:layout_width="150dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:background="@color/tabhost_background_pressed"
           android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

      <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/img_N1"
          android:layout_width="120dp"
          android:layout_height="120dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
          android:src="@drawable/mcdonalds_icon" />

      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/title_N1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:text="McDonals del CC Alcampo"
          android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
          android:textSize="15sp" />

      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/categoria_N1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:text="CATEGORIA"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

      <RelativeLayout 
          android:id="@+id/stars_and_distance_N1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/stars_N1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/stars_25"
              android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="7dp" />


          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/distance_N1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="200m"
              android:textSize="12sp"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />


          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/icon_pos_N1"
              android:layout_width="10dp"
              android:layout_height="10dp"
              android:src="@drawable/marker_distance"
              android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/distance_N1"
              android:layout_marginTop="7dp" />

      </RelativeLayout><LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/cartel_N1"
      android:layout_width="150dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/tabhost_background_pressed"
      android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/img_N1"
          android:layout_width="120dp"
          android:layout_height="120dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
          android:src="@drawable/mcdonalds_icon" />

      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/title_N1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:text="McDonals del CC Alcampo"
          android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
          android:textSize="15sp" />

      <TextView 
          android:id="@+id/categoria_N1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:text="CATEGORIA"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

      <RelativeLayout 
          android:id="@+id/stars_and_distance_N1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/stars_N1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:src="@drawable/stars_25"
              android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
              android:layout_marginTop="7dp" />


          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/distance_N1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="200m"
              android:textSize="12sp"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />


          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/icon_pos_N1"
              android:layout_width="10dp"
              android:layout_height="10dp"
              android:src="@drawable/marker_distance"
              android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/distance_N1"
              android:layout_marginTop="7dp" />

      </RelativeLayout>
  ```
- This is my main xml:

  ```
  <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/container_destacado"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

             <!-- Inflate multiple xml file here -->

        </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
  ```

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You could use something like

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

//to get the MainLayout
View view = inflater.inflate(container_destacado, null);
...
//Avoid pass null in the root it ignores spaces in the child layout

View inflatedLayout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, (ViewGroup) view, false);
containerDestacado.addView(inflatedLayout);
```

Comment: View view = inflater.inflate(container_destacado, null);
in this line i am getting error it is not taking my main layout as a parameter
@Adam

Answer (score 15):

You can implement this like below:

```
LayoutInflater linf;
LinearLayout rr;

linf = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
linf = LayoutInflater.from(activity.this);

rr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_destacado);

for (int i = 1; i < NoOfTimes; i++) {

    final View v = linf.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
    rr.addView(v);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_destacado);  // ll is the layout where your inflated layout will be added 
linflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
int pos = 0;
    while (pos < noOfTimes) 
    {
        View myView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null); //here item is the the layout you want to inflate 
        myView.setId(pos);
        /*
           You can change TextView text and ImageView images here e.g.
           TextView tv = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.title_N1);
           tv.setText(pos);

        */
        pos++;
        ll.addView(myView);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

In some point you should gain access to your inflater inside your activity, you can call it with this code:

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

Where context is this or this.getActivity() if it is a Fragment. Then inflate your layour with:

```
View layout = li.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null, false);
```

Then use addView(layout) to your container_destacado:

```
View containerDestacado = li.inflate(R.layout.container_destacado, null, false);
containerDestacado.addView(layout);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin code to do so:

```
 val layoutToInflate = 
 this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ly_custom_layout, 
  null)
container_destacado.addView(layoutToInflate )
```

Answer (score 2):

in Kotlin with editable textview elements on item.xml

```
  val item = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.item,null)
  val distance_N1_holder = item.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.distance_N1)
  distance_N1_holder.text = //dynamically generated value

  main.addView(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the LinearLayout on which you want to inflate other childs:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)parentView.findViewById(R.id.container_destacado);
```

Once you loaded the item.xml with an inflater, you can just use

```
container.addView(itemView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working code from one of my projects:

```
// The parent container
mNotificationOverlay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_destacado);   
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

for (Message message : m) {

    // Inflate the child layout on the fly
    final View notificationContainer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_overlay_linear_layout, null);
    notificationContainer.setTag(message.getNotificationId());

    // Access children of child container
    TextView notificationOverlayTitle = (TextView) notificationContainer.findViewById(R.id.notification_title_overlay);
    TextView notificationOverlayBody = (TextView) notificationContainer.findViewById(R.id.notification_body_overlay);
    ImageButton notificationOverlayCancelButton = (ImageButton) notificationContainer.findViewById(R.id.notification_cancel_overlay);

    // Perform desired operations
    notificationOverlayCancelButton.setTag(message.getNotificationId());
    notificationOverlayTitle.setText(message.getTitle());
    notificationOverlayBody.setText(message.getNotificationBody());
    mNotificationOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // Attach any listeners
    attachListenersToCancelView(notificationOverlayCancelButton);

    // Add view to parent container
    mNotificationOverlay.addView(notificationContainer);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If someone couldn't get the `addView()` it's because the view is not a layout.

Answer (score 0):

Three lines of code should be enough:

```
//The container 
container_destcado = findViewById(R.id.container_destcado);

//The item (layout) that you want to add to the container
final View item = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item,null,false);

//Adding the item to the container
container_destcado.addView(item);
```