# How to change location of Android xml source file with radio button?

Tags: android, xml, radio-button

I have 3 xml source files like this:

```
XmlPullParser xmlR =  params[0].getXml(R.xml.code_1);
XmlPullParser xmlR =  params[0].getXml(R.xml.code_2);
XmlPullParser xmlR =  params[0].getXml(R.xml.code_3);
```

And this is my radio button:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/separator2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/code_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="code_1"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/code_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="code_2"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
             />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/code_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="code_3" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

How to select **just one** of the xml files with radio button?
So, when I select one of radio button, the xml **code_1** or xml **code_2** or xml **code_3** will be used.

Thanks.

Comment: Use RadioGroup as a parent view for all your radio buttons so only 1 of them can be selected at a time

Comment: Can you explain with java code please..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to group your radio buttons in a RadioGroup[1] layout, then you'll have to set an OnCheckedChangeListener[2] this way you'll be able to know which radio button is selected at a time.

`RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)`

The checkedId relates to the selected RadioButton, so you can use your xml based on it.

[1] - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html
[2] - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html

Answer (score -1):

You need to inflate your xml programatically!!! Just do this and it will work!

Comment: I confuse with java code. Can you give me example for select just one of the xml with java code please..

Comment: read this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400415/inflate-layout-programmatically-within-another-layout 

And please, upvote this answer!