# Blend two views in Android

Tags: android, blend, multiple-views

Is it possible to blend two different views in different modes like Multiply, Add etc.

I have two views one is a RelativeLayout matching parent shape with a background image. Another one is ImageView (solid colored custom shape) inside the parent RelativeLayout.

I need to blend top ImageView to the background image in Multiply mode.
any kind of help would be appreciable.

Comment: Never heard about multiply mode in Android. I know two approaches to combine two views one through xml https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts, another through the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400415/inflate-layout-programmatically-within-another-layout

Comment: @Kirk_hehe, I need two separate layouts two blend with each other. It is like a Color Filter over a photgraph. The problem is my color filter is in custom shape.

Comment: I'm also working on a react-native app and was disappointed to find out this doesn't exist.