# How to add textview and editText according to data count

Tags: android

I'm building an app which will scan QRcode and get values from the database. I currently have listview for this purpose, What I want is to dynamically generate textView and editText according to data row count.

Comment: you can do it with listView

Comment: tried with a list view , but I can't add editText to listview.

Comment: Better to use [**`RecyclerView`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: why dont you just inflate a layout with editttext and textview and addview to parent layout. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400415/inflate-layout-programmatically-within-another-layout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use a Recycler view for this.

- create a layout with edit text and needed buttons
- Add this layout to recycle view using an [adapter](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)
- Make sure to use [TextWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42951863/11152084).Things will get crazy when you scroll.